# How can I customize the legend in a scatterplot to meet several requirements?

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Question**:

How can I customize the legend in the scatterplot to meet the following requirements:

1. Display specific opacity levels (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, and 0.9) in the legend.
2. Provide corresponding representative points or shapes in the legend with the correct opacity values.
3. Ensure that the legend accurately reflects the varying transparency of data points.
4. Maintain clarity and effectiveness in communicating the data's transparency through the legend.

**Context:**
Imagine you are working on a data visualization project in R using ggplot2.

- You have a dataset called 'mydata' with three variables: 'X', 'Y', and 'Opacity'.
- 'Opacity' represents the transparency of data points and ranges from 0.1 to 0.9.
- You have successfully created a scatterplot showing data points with varying transparency based on 'Opacity'.
- However, you want to customize the legend to show specific opacity levels (0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9) and provide corresponding representative points with the correct opacity in the legend.

```
library(ggplot2)

# Create a sample dataset
set.seed(42)
mydata <- data.frame(
  X = rnorm(100),
  Y = rnorm(100),
  Opacity = runif(100, min = 0.1, max = 0.9)
)

# Create a scatterplot with varying transparency
scatter_plot <- ggplot(
  data = mydata,
  aes(x = X, y = Y, alpha = Opacity)
) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(range = c(0.1, 0.9)) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot with Varying Transparency")

print(scatter_plot)
```

Comment: welcome to SO! Lots of really helpful folks here. 

What code have to tried so far regarding the plot legend? Did you search for answers in previous SO questions? 

Here's pretty much all you'll need: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve your desired result by setting the `breaks=` and (!!) the `limits=` of the `alpha` scale like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(
  data = mydata,
  aes(x = X, y = Y, alpha = Opacity)
) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(
    range = c(0.1, 0.9),
    breaks = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9),
    limits = c(.1, .9)
  ) +
  labs(title = "Scatterplot with Varying Transparency")
```

[image]